# Build failed: could not resolve storage source: googleapi: Error 404: Not Found, notFound

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy the following cloud function to write in a bigquery table from cloud storage:

```
def csvloader(data,context):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    client = bigquery.Client()
    table_ref = client.dataset("dataset").table("table")
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    uri = "gs://xxxx/xxx.csv"
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(uri, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
    load_job.result()
    destination_table = client.get_table(table_ref)
```

The runtime is Python 3.8 and the region europe-west3

The error that I receive is:

```
Build failed: could not resolve storage source: googleapi: Error 404: Not Found, notFound
```

The storage is well referenced and exists and the service account has the following permissions

```
  role: roles/bigquery.admin
  role: roles/bigquery.dataEditor
  role: roles/bigquery.dataOwner
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent
```

Comment: Can you check that the GCS URL (gs://xxxx/xxx.csv) actually points to something?  Maybe open a GCP Cloud shell and run:

gsutil ls gs://xxxx/xxx.csv


Which source statement is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi Kolban, yes it is pointing to an existing location $ gsutil ls gs://sp500components/SP500stocks.csv
gs://sp500components/SP500stocks.csv

Comment: Is the text of the error message from your code? (could not resolve storage source).   Are we able to determine which statement is throwing the error?

Comment: I'm not yet understanding where the message comes from that would give us context on the puzzle.  When I Google search "could not resolve storage source" ... I don't seem to find any matches.  What I'd like us to learn is what app/service/process is issuing the message to give us context on the puzzle.

Comment: @Kolban the issue comes in the two last lines from 'load_job.result()'. I've executed separtately and I receive the following error: google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/xxx/datasets
/tfm/tables/xxxx?prettyPrint=false: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Comment: Ahh!!  That is a very different error from a 404 not found.  A 403 is a permissions error that says that the caller doesn't have permission to make the request.  Given the nature of the API ... two resources are being accessed ... the GCS object as the source of the data and the BQ table as the target of the data.  It isn't clear to me which one is having the permissions error.  You'll want to validate/determine the identity that cloud function is running as and make sure it has both GCS read permissions and BQ create/write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue comes from the permissions, in order to fix this:

1. Click the Cloud Function on the [UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list)
2. Click the `EDIT` button on the top of the page
3. Click on the section `VARIABLES, NETWORKING AND ADVANCED SETTINGS` to open it
4. In the bottom part verify that you're using the correct Service Account
5. If the Service Account is the correct one, then add the role of `Storage Admin`, wait a few minutes and try again the Cloud Function

Also the original issue mentioned in the question:

`Error: Not found: URI gs://bucket/file.csv at new ApiError`

Comes from the fact that the object mentioned isn't located in the route mentioned, be sure that:

```
uri = "gs://xxxx/xxx.csv"
```

Is pointing to the correct bucket/folder/object, try looking for it as mentioned in the comments section:

```
gsutil ls gs://sp500components/SP500stocks.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this because I had the same problem. It seems you have already checked the roles, so this may not be *your* solution, but this is what worked for me:

I was using some other part of GCP (Cloud Run) and I realised that the CLI was logged into my Compute Engine default service account, rather than my App Engine default service account. Switching to App Engine resolved the error.

I believe there are legacy reasons why you have two separate accounts, but it seems you have to be logged in with the right one depending on which part of GCP you are using.

You can list your accounts:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

And then login to the correct one:

```
gcloud config set account <ACCOUNT>
gcloud auth login
```